# NavigationLink touch area

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm trying to use `NavigationLink` inside `List`. For a specific reason, it is in `.background` with `EmptyView()`.

```
var body: some View {
    List {
        Section {
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30, alignment: .center)
                    .opacity(selected ? 1 : 0)
                Text("TEST")
                Spacer()
            }
            .onTapGesture {
                selected.toggle()
            }
            .background(
                NavigationLink(destination: WifiView()) { EmptyView() }
                    .disabled(isPad)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is the touch area for the `NavigationLink` is not as expected.

[image: .background area]

`.background`'s area is as above.

[image: NavigationLink and EmptyView area]

but `NavigationLink` and `EmptyView`'s area is as above. I tried to force the frame with `.frame` but it won't change.

What am I missing?

Comment: Empty view means that there is nothing to click on. Put what you want to click on where you have the empty view

Comment: Same result with other views list Text.

Comment: Probably because you have it I. The background too the link is hidden in the back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this, works well for me:

```
var body: some View {
    List {
        Section {
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30, alignment: .center)
                    .opacity(selected ? 1 : 0)
                Text("TEST")
                Spacer()
            }
                .contentShape(Rectangle())  // <--- here
                .onTapGesture {
                    selected.toggle()
                }
                .background(
                    NavigationLink(destination: WifiView()) { EmptyView() }
                        .disabled(isPad)
                )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It didn't really fix the issue, but helped me to find the right answer. It was combination was 2 issues and the `contentShape` fixed one.

Answer (score 2):

To distill the accepted answer: all you need to do is to add `.contentShape(Rectangle())` to the same element which has `.onTapGesture`.  This solution works for any container, not just `List`.

E.g. if you have:

```
VStack {
   // ...
}
.onTapGesture {
   // ...
}
```

Add `contentShape` to the same element:

```
VStack {
   // ...
}
.contentShape(Rectangle())
.onTapGesture {
   // ...
}
```

Rationale:

> If you add a tap gesture to a container SwiftUI view, such as VStack or HStack, then SwiftUI only adds the gesture to the parts of the container that have something inside – large parts of the stack are likely to be untappable.
>
> If this is what you want then the default behavior is fine. However, if you want to change the shape of hit tests – the area that responds to taps – then you should use the contentShape() modifier with the shape you want.

([source](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-control-the-tappable-area-of-a-view-using-contentshape))