# Make the hit testing for a NavigationLink from a Rectangle with plain button style and no foregroundColor (clear Color) include the empty space

Tags: swiftui, navigation, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview, hittest

The problem is to make a `NavigationLink` from a `Rectangle` which:

1. does not have a foreground color (or has a `Color.clear` foreground color) and
2. has `buttonStyle` set to `PlainButtonStyle()` or `.plain` (to remove the blue text overlay)

have hit testing such that gestures in the empty space trigger navigation.

Simple example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                // tap gestures anywhere in the rectangle work as expected
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("target 1")) {
                    Rectangle().foregroundColor(.red)
                }
                .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())

                // touch gestures anywhere in the rectangle don't navigate (if this were a ZStack with some Text in the Rectangle, only gestures on the Text would work)
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("target 2")) {
                    Rectangle().stroke(lineWidth: 2)
                }
                .buttonStyle(.plain)
            }
            .padding(20)
        }
    }
}
```

Preview:

[image]

The problem is that gestures inside the second (white or clear) rectangle don't trigger navigation. Removing the `buttonStyle(.plain)` is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add a `contentShape` modifier to tell the system how to do hit testing for the `NavigationLink`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("target 2")) {
                    Rectangle()
                        .stroke(lineWidth: 2)
                        .contentShape(Rectangle())
                }
                .buttonStyle(.plain)
            }
            .padding(20)
        }
    }
}
```

I suspect this has to do with how the hit testing is managed for the `PlainButtonStyle`, as alluded to in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74869803/12109043):

> If you add a tap gesture to a container SwiftUI view, such as VStack or HStack, then SwiftUI only adds the gesture to the parts of the container that have something inside – large parts of the stack are likely to be untappable.
>
> If this is what you want then the default behavior is fine. However, if you want to change the shape of hit tests – the area that responds to taps – then you should use the contentShape() modifier with the shape you want.

([source](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-control-the-tappable-area-of-a-view-using-contentshape))